# forEach use index to get next item

Tags: javascript, foreach

I tried to get the next element cause i need position of this element to draw a line that connect both. The error message i got back is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')

```
var timeslot = document.getElementsByClassName('uk-card');
console.log(timeslot[3]);

Array.from(timeslot).forEach(function(element, index) {
 
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  var next = timeslot[index + 1]; /ERROR Line
  var rectNext = next.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
  console.log(rectNext.top, rectNext.right, rectNext.bottom, rectNext.left);

});
```

Comment: Well, there isn't going to be a `next` item for the last item in the array, is there? What do you expect to happen then? (And what do you want to happen then?)

Comment: Ah. You are right. I need to check if it last element and don't do it for the last.

Answer (score 0):

Quentin - thanks for your help.
I got the error cause the last element hast not a next element.
So I add a if and now it works.